# How to read Excel in Mac using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I wonder how we can read an excel file from C# code in a Mac.

Generally we cannot use Microsoft Excel in MAC. I tried to do it by converting the Excel into a .csv and then read the same.

Is there any alternate for this? Any better approach will help

Thanks in advance

Comment: If only there was some kind of website where you could search for answers? What have you tried already? Please post some code.

Comment: .NET is written for **Windows**

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman That is not true, C# is cross platform and open source.

Comment: how you run C# in mac ?

Comment: Do you want to run C#-Code on a mac or do you want to convert an excel File via Windows. If it's the first look at the Mono-Project

Comment: As of May 04, 2015 Roslyn can compile C# to native code - do you use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can use the [ExcelDataReader library](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader)

It's a cross-platform library.

Short sample from github:

```
FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

//1. Reading from a binary Excel file ('97-2003 format; *.xls)
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);

//2. Reading from a OpenXml Excel file (2007 format; *.xlsx)
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);

//3. DataSet - The result of each spreadsheet will be created in the result.Tables
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

//4. DataSet - Create column names from first row
excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

//5. Data Reader methods
while (excelReader.Read())
{
    //excelReader.GetInt32(0);
}

//6. Free resources (IExcelDataReader is IDisposable)
excelReader.Close();
```